# Azure synapse link for D365 dataverse event based trigger for storage change

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-synapse-pipeline, event-based-components

I created azure synapse link for dataverse to replicate data from D365 Finance and Operation tables into Synapse followed by SQL Server. I need to create an event based trigger, whenever I add new table, I want my datacopy pipeline to get executed. For D365 I see lot of folder options after I select my storage account and container, not sure which folder to be used.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlcYp.png)

When I just select nothing equivalent to root, I see huge number of options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8FcP.png)

If someone can help on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The way Synapse link works is to create a new folder every 15 minutes with the new data and also to update the model.json in the root folder with the nee metadata.

According to Microsoft documentation, the best approach is to set the storage event to only the model.json file, so every end of Synapse link cycle will trigger your pipeline to run.

See detailed steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-pipelines?tabs=synapse-analytics

Note - you must set up an event subscription filter (the last step) otherwise your trigger will run twice.